# One Note API for office365 Home integration

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I  have a web application with which I want to integrate One Note.

My License is office 365 home.

Can I Integrate OneNote API with my PHP application with office 365 home subscription? or do we have to get some higher level subscription?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. Try signing in with your account in the graph explorer and making a few API calls to get your OneNote content - you can quickly confirm that way.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer